# Limitar quantidade de requests na query

Tags: php, query

Possuo está *query* que faz um request por vez, em ordem aleatória.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `viperusers` WHERE vip < 1 AND username != :username ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Explicando, seleciono todos meus usuários, se for o meu ignora, como podem ver limitei pra 1 pra cada reload na página pegar um usuário aleatório.

Toda vez que passa por um usuário conta +1 da minha *Database*, ou seja a cada request soma +1, mas tenho um problema, gostaria que quando selecionasse o mesmo usuário não fizesse essa contagem.

- **Tem como fazer isso?**

Está aqui o código:

```
public function counter($select_data, $following, $is_vip) {
  global $followersLimit, $follow;

  $followersAttempts = (int) $select_data[0]->count;

  if (($is_vip && $follow->_return->status == 1) 
        || !$is_vip) {
      $followersAttempts++;
  }

  if ($followersAttempts > $select_data[0]->count) {
    $this->_db->update('viperusers', array(
      'count' => $followersAttempts
    ), array(
      'username' => $select_data[0]->username
    ));
  }

  if ($followersAttempts >= $followersLimit) {
      $timer = ($is_vip) 
        ?$this->select_configs()[0]->timer_vip 
        :$this->select_configs()[0]->timer_free;

      $select_data[0]->timer = strtotime('+' . $timer . ' minutes');

      $this->_db->update('viperusers', array(
        'count' => 0,
        'timer' => $select_data[0]->timer
      ), array(
        'username' => $select_data[0]->username
      ));

      return json_encode(array(
        'follow'  => false,
        'timer'   => $timer
      ));
  }

  return json_encode(array(
    'follow'    => true,
    'followed'  => $select_data[0]->username,
    'following' => $following,
    'count'     => $followersAttempts
  ));
}

public function followers() {
  global $followersLimit, $follow;

  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 
      && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $username = Session::get('username');

    $select_data = $this->_requests->select_data($username);

    if ($select_data[0]->timer > time()) {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'follow'  => false,
        'timer'   => ceil((($select_data[0]->timer - time()) / 60))
      ));

      exit;
    }

    $select_random = $this->_requests->select_random($username);

    $follow = new Follow;

    $follow->setCookieFile(SMVC . 'application' . 
                              DS . 'cookies' . DS . $select_random[0]->username . '.txt');

    $follow->initialize( $select_data[0]->ds_user_id, 
        $select_random[0]->csrftoken );

    if ($follow->_return->status != $select_random[0]->status) {
      $this->_requests->set_status($select_random[0]->username, $follow->_return->status);
    }

    $followersLimit = $this->_requests->select_configs()[0]->followers_x;

    if ($this->_requests->select_is_vip($username)) {
      $is_vip = true;
      $followersLimit = 2 * $followersLimit;
    } else {
      $is_vip = false;
    }
    echo $this->_requests->counter($select_data, 
                                    $select_random[0]->username, $is_vip);
  }
}
```

Aqui está verificação de vips:

```
public function select_random($username) {
    if ($this->select_is_vip($username)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `viperusers` WHERE vip < 1 AND username != :username ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `viperusers` WHERE vip = 0 AND username != :username ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    }

    $query = $this->_db->select($sql, array(
        ':username' => $username
    ));

    if (empty($query[0]->username)) {
        return $this->select_random($username);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: O que tem que fazer e verificar se o usuário que foi sorteado já esta sendo seguido.

Comment: Sim, pensei nisso, mas como fazer? eis a questão fiz isso tudo porém travei ai

Comment: @ÐvÐ isso mesmo.

Comment: Se for o mesmo usuário não quero que conte. Só o próximo que ainda não foi selecionado.

Comment: @ÐvÐ significa que esse usuário está ativo. se for != de 1 ele não está ativo, mas ele msm assim seleciona e soma na contagem. o que não era pra acontecer.

Comment: @ÐvÐ, vou editar a pergunta com o código do controller, e tem outra query que pucha os não vips também.

Comment: @ÐvÐ editei.....

Comment: @ÐvÐ, sim, não tem pq eu perdi totalmente a noção, a lógica, não consegui fazer a verificação, aí vim aqui pedir uma luz divina.

Comment: E os não vips? mesma coisa?

Comment: Os vips precisam ter status == 1, os não vips não precisam

Comment: Ou melhor: `if ( (($is_vip && $follow->_return->status == 1) || !$is_vip) && $followersAttempts == 0 ){`

Comment: @ÐvÐ, seguinte, parou de contar os selecionados porém não soma os outros. estou tentando arrumar.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns detalhes que percebi:
1) Eu não vi o que a função select_is_vip faz, mas porque você já não guarda se o usuário é vip aqui:
'username' => $select_data[0]->username,
'is_vip' => ($select_data[0]->vip==0?false:true)
Assim evita ficar chamando a função select_is_vip.
2) Onde você está guardando no banco de dados esse mais 1?

Mas se você fizer assim, chegará uma hora que não terá mais usuários. Por exemplo, se na sua base de dados tiver 10 usuários e der 10 refresh´s não terá usuário. Falo isto, pois na sua função você está correndo o risco de entrar num loop infinito quando isto acontecer, pois tem essa linha de comando: if (empty($query[0]->username)) {
        return $this->select_random($username);
    }